# OrientDb - How to add a new edge between two existing vertices mapping with one common property?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Is there a way to add an edge between existing vertices which maps one common property between them ?

Example -
Class1 has three properties - A,B,C
and
Class 2 has three properties - A,D,E
where Class1.A has same values as that in Class2.A

How can I create an edge which maps all A values in Class1 to all A values in Class2 without reloading the data ?

Also, is there a way I can achieve this from the User Interface ?
I can see an option to create an Edge there but it does not ask for the property value to map with.

Note: I am using orientdb-community-importers-2.2.27

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
create edge <edge name> from (select from class1 where A IN (select A from class2)) to (select from class2 where A IN (select A from class1))
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. But if there is a huge data involved, it slows down the performance to a great scale.